# IDE for Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm searching for a decent IDE or form designer for Tkinter. So far, I have only come across [Rapyd-Tk](http://www.bitflipper.ca/rapyd/) which I tried, but is very outdated and is quite buggy.

Unfortunately that's all I found, and other questions asking for this are also rather old, so is there any recent, working designers for Tkinter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nice IDE for wxPython or Tkinter GUI Development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800849/nice-ide-for-wxpython-or-tkinter-gui-development)

Comment: @Makoto - All the suggestions in that question are for wxPython.

Comment: This question is inappropriate for StackOverflow. [SO is not a link engine or search site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549/172661).

Comment: If I answered your question, please mark it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one.

http://page.sourceforge.net/ - website
http://page.sourceforge.net/html/intro.html - documentation

Works on linux. Haven't tried working on any sort of project with it yet, I just made sure it worked before posting. Keep in mind that tkinter is sufficiently easy to use that you don't save much time with drag-and-drop. It would be almost easier to just write the code in the first place.

Works with python2.6 and 3.x. Requires ttk package in addition to tkinter (included with most python distributions, I know python2.6 or 3.x on windows does have it).